# Error: while parsing a block mapping; expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart in cassandra.yaml file

Tags: cassandra, centos7

I'm trying to execute Cassandra on the cento7 VPS server. But when I start Cassandra with  `systemctl start cassandra` command line and I get below error in log :

```
INFO  [main] 2020-07-03 12:45:23,116 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
ERROR [main] 2020-07-03 12:45:23,211 CassandraDaemon.java:774 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: while parsing a block mapping; expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart;  in 'reader', line 708, column 2:
     broadcast_rpc_address: 127.0.0.1
     ^
```

cassandra.yaml screenshot
[image]

Comment: I suggest to paste file into something like http://www.yamllint.com/ - most probably you have some space in the previous lines, like, after `rpc_port`

Comment: @AlexOtt Dear Alex. I did but I got the same result as before

Comment: what version of Cassandra?

Comment: @AlexOtt 3.11.6-1

Comment: because it says `column 2`, it should be a space or tab character on the line 708 instead of the empty line...